# Pandas :TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I am trying to do the machine learning practice problem of Heart disease , dataset from kaggle.
Then i tried to split data into train set and test set and after that combing models into single function and predicting,this error shows up in jupyter notebook .

Here's my code:

```
# Split data into X and y
X = df.drop("target", axis=1)
y = df["target"]
```

Spliting

```
# Split data into train and test sets
np.random.seed(42)

# Split into train & test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
```

Prediction function

```
    # Put models in a dictionary
models = {"Logistic Regression": LogisticRegression(),
          "KNN": KNeighborsClassifier(),
          "Random Forest": RandomForestClassifier()}

# Create a function to fit and score models
def fit_and_score(models, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    """
    Fits and evaluates given machine learning models.
    models : a dict of differetn Scikit-Learn machine learning models
    X_train : training data (no labels)
    X_test : testing data (no labels)
    y_train : training labels
    y_test : test labels
    """
    # Set random seed
    np.random.seed(42)
    # Make a dictionary to keep model scores
    model_scores = {}
    # Loop through models
    for name, model in models.items():
        # Fit the model to the data
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        # Evaluate the model and append its score to model_scores
        model_scores[name] = model.score(X_test, y_test)
    return model_scores
```

And when i run this code , that error shows up

```
    model_scores = fit_and_score(models=models,
                             X_train=X_train,
                             X_test=X_test,
                             y_train=y_train,
                             y_test=y_test)

model_scores
```

This is error
[image]

Comment: Where is the error happening?

Comment: After my last code

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `X_train`, `y_train`, or both, seem to have entries that are not float numbers.

At some point in the code, try using

```
X_train = X_train.astype(float)
y_train = y_train.astype(float)
X_test = X_test.astype(float)
y_test = y_test.astype(float)
```

Either this will work and the error will go away, or one of the conversions will fail, at which point you will need to decide how (or if) you want to encode the data as a float.